# Which Magento 2 directories can I exclude in PhpStorm?

Tags: magento2, optimization, phpstorm

I'm looking to try and speed up the indexing process in PhpStorm, so I'm looking to find out what directories can I safely ignore without compromising the code completion and hinting.

The only source I have found is here:

https://mirasvit.com/blog/guide-for-setting-up-phpstorm-for-magento-2-developments.html

But I wanted to know if there are other places I can exclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All listed directories are okay there. But instead of few sub directories of **var** folder, you can exclude entire **var** folder. Like **pub** folder.

Comment: It helps, there i was hoping to field a few more answers, there are a lot of files in M2, and a bigger discussion  on what needs to be track and not is what i'm going for. If no one else chimes in, i will get you the points!

Comment: Don't exclude complete `var/` cause you don't want to exclude `var/generation/` for validation and hinting of generated classes (like Factories etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no real agreement about this, as there are dir in var that have php classes in them that the IDE might want to index (`generation` being the main one as @7ochem points out in his comment). I think in the end, if there are performance issue with indexing taking too much time, it's time to rethink how I'm running Magento 2 and editing the files in phpStorm. But to start, @Kishan and the article i posted are a good solution.